# uploading a file in grails

Tags: grails, input

I am trying to upload a file in grails in my gsp I have:

```
<g:form id="update" url="[action: 'updateStatus',]">
     <g:textArea name="message" value="" cols="3" rows="1"/><br/>
     <g:textField id="tagField" name="tag" value=""/><br/>
     <input id="inputField" type="file" name="myFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
     <g:submitButton name="Update Status"/>
 </g:form>
```

In my controller i have:

```
 def updateStatus(String message) {

        if (params.myFile){
            def f = request.getFile('myFile')

        }
```

The request get file is failing with this error:

```
No signature of method: org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.getFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [myFile]
```

Any ideas why this is as I have and are using getFile in my other controllers which works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here is working file submit:

the form (gsp)

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p><input type='file' name="cfile"/></p>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

the controller that will store submitted file into 'D:/submitted_file':

```
def index() {
    if(params.cfile){
        if(params.cfile instanceof org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile){
            new FileOutputStream('d:/submitted_file').leftShift( params.cfile.getInputStream() );
            //params.cfile.transferTo(new File('D:/submitted_file'));
        }else{
            log.error("wrong attachment type [${cfile.getClass()}]");
        }
    }
}
```

this works for me (grails 2.0.4)

Answer (score 4):

You need `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the `g:form` tag to make the browser use a multipart request.

Comment: From your edit it looks like you put the enctype on the `input` tag, but it needs to be on the form tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

In order to upload a file you must set the *enctype* on the form.  To do so you can make use of the `<g:uploadForm>` which is identical to the standard form tag except that it **sets the *enctype* attribute to "multipart/form-data" automatically.**

I prefer to make use of the [Grails Selfie Plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/selfie) an *Image / File Upload Plugin* to attach files to your domain models, upload to a CDN, validate content, or produce thumbnails.

**Domain**

```
import com.bertramlabs.plugins.selfie.Attachment

class Book {
   String name
   Attachment photo

   static attachmentOptions = [
       photo: [
           styles: [
              thumb: [width: 50, height: 50, mode: 'fit'],
              medium: [width: 250, height: 250, mode: 'scale']
          ]
       ]
   ]

   static embedded = ['photo'] //required

   static constraints = {
      photo contentType: ['image/jpeg','image/png'], fileSize:1024*1024 // 1mb
   }
}
```

**GSP**

```
<g:uploadForm name="myUpload" controller="upload" action="updateStatus">
    <input type="file" name="myFile" />
</g:uploadForm>
```

**Controller**

```
class PhotoController {
   def upload() {
      def photo = new Photo(params)
      if(!photo.save()) {
         println "Error Saving! ${photo.errors.allErrors}"
      }
      redirect view: "index"
   }
}
```

**Sources**

[1. uploadFrom](http://docs.grails.org/2.5.1/ref/Tags/uploadForm.html)

[2. selfie plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/selfie)